# In JavaScript how to make sure that array has at least one specific element and the others meet another condition?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, validation, filter

Given an array that contains some status string,
I want to validate if the array contains at least one `sleeping` status and then validate if the rest of the statuses are either `ok` or `sleeping`.

So a valid array is `['ok', 'sleeping', 'sleeping', 'ok']` and an invalid array will be something like `const states = ['ready', 'working','onBreak','sleeping', 'ok', 'sleeping']`

What I have come up with so far is this:

```js
const validArray = ['ok', 'sleeping', 'sleeping', 'ok'];

const isvalid = validArray.some( x => x === 'sleeping')

if(isValid){
  const canDoStuff = validArray.some( x => !['ok','sleeping'].includes(x))
  if(canDoStuff){
    doStuff()  
  }
}
```

Ideally, I would like to validate that in a single loop,and not two loops.

Comment: Doing it in a single loop is weird.  Because the test for "if sleeping exists" can terminate once it finds one, while the test for "something other than ok or sleeping" may have to evaluate all the way to the end

Comment: @Taplar I don't see anything weird about using a single loop. In the worst case (where all entries are either 'ok' or 'sleeping') you have to scan the entire array anyway. You can only break out early if you encounter a value other than those two. This is the case whether you use one loop or multiple loops. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63623819/1202830) for an example of a single-loop solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than `.some` to check if there's one `sleeping` item, use `.includes`.

But, your other `.some` isn't implementing the right logic either; `doStuff` will only run if there's at least one item which *doesn't* match. Use `.every` instead, and check that each *does* match:

```js
const validate = input => (
  input.includes('sleeping') &&
  input.every(x => ['ok', 'sleeping'].includes(x))
);

console.log(validate(['ok', 'sleeping', 'sleeping', 'ok']));
console.log(validate(['ready', 'working','onBreak','sleeping', 'ok', 'sleeping']));
```

Comment: Mostly for giggles... but I tried to test perf of doing the include check before/after the every check with different array contents... interestingly different browsers find one way or the other to perform better https://www.jsben.ch/8IwR1 - my general thought is that if you want to be able to bail out early, test the every() first, then try the includes but YMMV.

Comment: @scunliffe Thanks for creating that interesting test suite. The performance for each case is dominated by the `console.log` calls, though. I added a new version of the test at https://jsben.ch/vrzl1 which removes those calls and also adds the for loop code from my answer. With or without `console.log`, I did notice quite a bit of variation from one run to another in the same browser. Sometimes the "includes first" is faster, other times the "every first". In all cases the for loop is faster than either.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the fastest code, use a simple `for` loop:

```js
'use strict';

function isValid( array ) {
    let sleeping = false;
    for( const item of array ) {
        if( item === 'sleeping' ) {
            sleeping = true;
        } else if( item !== 'ok' ) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return sleeping;
}

function test( array ) {
    console.log( isValid(array) ? 'Valid:' : 'Invalid:', array );
}

test( [ 'ok', 'sleeping', 'sleeping', 'ok' ] );
test( [ 'ready', 'working','onBreak','sleeping', 'ok', 'sleeping' ] );
```

This is a bit more code than the other answers suggest, but it will be faster than any of them.

In particular, the accepted answer uses two loops, not one. You don't see the loops directly because they are hidden inside the `.includes()` and `.every()` calls.

I don't mean this as a criticism of that code - it is very clean and simple, which I always like. But when performance counts, it can help to write old-school code that lets you combine multiple loops into one.

Of course it is always wise to benchmark when performance may matter, so I took the test that @scunliffe created (thanks!) and added a test that uses this for loop: https://jsben.ch/vrzl1

If you need to support old versions of Internet Explorer, use a numeric `for` loop instead of the `for-of` loop, and `var` instead of `let` and `const`.

Comment: I think there's value in the simple for loop and being able to fully control the tests within it, however I think the OP was considering an array to be valid if all entries are *either* ok *or* sleeping... and at least one of the values is "sleeping".

Comment: @scunliffe I'm pretty sure that is exactly what this code does. It returns false if any item is not 'sleeping' and not 'ok'. If all items are either 'sleeping' or 'ok', then it returns true if at least one item is 'sleeping', or false otherwise. Can you point to an error in the logic, or do you have a test case that fails?

Comment: Doh you’re right I misread the “!==“ as “===“, your code is fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple for-loop as follow:

```js
const validate = arr => {
  let foundSleeping = false;
  for (let str of arr) {
    if (!["sleeping", "ok"].includes(str)) return false;
    if (str === "sleeping") foundSleeping = true;
  }
  
  return foundSleeping;
};


console.log(validate(['ok', 'sleeping', 'sleeping', 'ok']));
console.log(validate(['ready', 'working','onBreak','sleeping', 'ok', 'sleeping']));
```