Typescript - if array contains `x` then it must also have `y` and `z`
In typescript how would I create a conditional type that states:
If array has x then it must also have y and z.
Example:
const allGroups = [ 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']

const group1 = [ 'w' ] // valid
const group2 = [ 'x' ] // invalid
const group3 = [ 'x', 'y' ] // invalid
const group4 = [ 'x', 'y', 'z' ] // valid

WIP: ts playground

What have you tried so far?

Is that at type level (so, TS is required) or just in the array (so, plain JS)?

Is [ 'y', 'x', 'z' ] valid or invalid?

this answers your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/63623589/6796856

@Caleth that is valid as the order does not matter

@HarunYilmaz working on a TS playground, will post the link to show what I've got so far

There is no specific type that works this way. You could write a generic type and a helper function as shown in this playground link. If you want to see this as an answer, let me know.

This doesn't work as a sensible type. The only thing you can do is exhaustively list the valid cases. You can't name a type T such that T[] checks other elements.
type Valid = [ 'w' ] | [ 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z' ] | [ 'w', 'y', 'x', 'z' ] | ... | [ 'x', 'y', 'z' ] | [ 'y', 'x', 'z' ] | ...

(... denote the remaining combinations)

Thanks! Looks like I need to re-think how this should work then. Appreciated

This is not generic. One cannot write every permutation-combination.

@RitikBanger I know. There isn't a generic solution.

Here is a type only version:
Typescript Lang
type Contains<T extends readonly any[], U> = U extends T[number] ? true : false;
type ContainsAll<T extends readonly any[], U extends readonly any[]> = U extends [infer F, ...infer R]
  ? Contains<T, F> extends true
    ? ContainsAll<T, R>
    : false
  : true;

type RequiresYAndZIfX<T extends readonly any[]> = Contains<T, 'x'> extends true
  ? ContainsAll<T, ['y', 'z']> extends true
    ? true
    : false
  : true;

type AssertValidGroup<T extends readonly any[]> = RequiresYAndZIfX<T> extends true ? T : never;

// Valid groups
const group1: AssertValidGroup<['w']> = ['w'];
const group4: AssertValidGroup<['x', 'y', 'z']> = ['x', 'y', 'z'];

// Invalid groups - these lines will cause a compile-time error
const group2: AssertValidGroup<['x']> = ['x'];
const group3: AssertValidGroup<['x', 'y']> = ['x', 'y'];

It can be easily achieved by creating a custom type and a type predicate to enforce the condition.
type ValidGroup = Array<'w' | 'x' | 'y' | 'z'>;

const allGroups: ValidGroup = ['w', 'x', 'y', 'z'];

function isValidGroup(group: ValidGroup): group is (Array<'w'> | Array<'w' | 'x' | 'y' | 'z'>) {
  if (group.includes('x')) {
    return group.includes('y') && group.includes('z');
  }
  return true;
}

const group1: ValidGroup = ['w']; // valid
const group2: ValidGroup = ['x']; // invalid
const group3: ValidGroup = ['x', 'y']; // invalid
const group4: ValidGroup = ['x', 'y', 'z']; // valid


this only works at run time if you call isValidGroup()?

true, updated the answer with a new link.

somebody removed the code from TS playground, adding that here directly.
